# Is it possible to embed non-fullscreen video in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, video

I know in the old days of iPhone OS 2.x this was clearly impossible. But how about now? Did they finally find a way to enable this? I need to play a movie in a small region of the screen. About 250x250 points only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Possible after SDk 4.0

use 
[[movieplayer view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];

Ashish Mathur

[ashiPhone](http://ashiphone.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in iOS3.2+ (ie on any iPad or on iPhone with iOS4).

You need to use MPMoviePlayerViewController instead of MPMoviePlayerController, and setup its view as you need.